# how to use callback data in telegram bot

Tags: php, bots, telegram

i'm using this library `https://github.com/Eleirbag89/TelegramBotPHP`  to create telegram bot

i want to get user tweeter username like:@username

how to use callback data and then use callback_data value

ex:

```
bot:  username
user: @alex
bot: password
user: 985468



        if($text == ' Submit your Detalis'){
        
        $option = array(
        
            array($telegram->buildInlineKeyBoardButton('✅ Done', $url, $callback_data = 'checkIsMember')) );
        $keyb = $telegram->buildInlineKeyBoard($option);
        $content = array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 'reply_markup' => $keyb, 'text' => '
        
        Join Our Telegram Channel 
         <b> Click "✅ Done" to continue </b>
        
        ');
        $telegram->sendMessage($content);
        
        }
        
        if($text == 'checkIsMember'){
        
          $content = array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => '

         Submit your Twitter username below (Included @)
        
        Ex : @username
        
          ');
        $telegram->sendMessage($content);
        
        }
```

Comment: You should use Database to store the user status, Like `input_twitter_username` or `none`.

Then check `if (status == 'input_twitter_username')` then do whatever with message.text

Answer (score 1):

Set webhook on file where bot is placed Site must have SSL (https).

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot(your token)/setWebhook?url=https://example.com/bot_directory/bot.php
```

Than process data and write bot

```
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

$botToken = "(your token)";
$botAPI = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $botToken;

$msg = $update['message']['text'];
$user_id = $update['message']['from']['id'];

//Simple send button when user send message
$data = http_build_query([
    'text' => 'Hi it is my bot',
    'chat_id' => $update['message']['from']['id'],
]);
$keyboard = json_encode([
    "inline_keyboard" => [
        [
            [
                "text" => "say Hi",
                "callback_data" => "say_h"
            ],
        ]
    ],
    "resize_keyboard" => true
]);

file_get_contents($botAPI . "/sendMessage?{$data}&reply_markup={$keyboard}");

if (isset($update['callback_query'])) {
    if ($update['callback_query']['data'] == 'say_h'){
        // your code here when button pressed
    }
}
```